# Confusion regarding to_char and to_number

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

First of all, I am aware about basics.

`select to_number('A231') from dual;` --this will not work but

`select to_char('123') from dual;`-- this will work

`select to_number('123') from dual;`-- this will also work

Actually in my package, we have 2 tables `A(X number`) and `B(Y varchar)` There are many columns but we are worried about only `X` and `Y`. `X` contains values only numeric like `123,456` etc but Y contains some `string` and some `number` for eg `'123','HR123','Hello'`. We have to join these 2 tables. its legacy application so we are not able to change tables and columns.
Till this time below condition was working properly

```
to_char(A.x)=B.y;
```

But since there is index on Y, performance team suggested us to do
`A.x=to_number(B.y);`  it is running in dev env.

My question is, in any circumstances will this query give error? if it picks `'123'` definitely it will give `123`. but if it picks `'AB123'` then it will fail. can it fail? can it pick `'AB123'` even when it is getting joined with other `table`.

Comment: 1. As your post, seem the index is in A.x, not Y. 

2. Your performance team is right but that is only in theory, and in your real data seem that B.y have many `not_number_string`, so that you should not do as their suggest. 

3. For your question, your query would always give errors as long as your B table have `not_number_string` in `y` column.

Comment: The performance team got it backwards. Their suggestion would even prevent the existing index from being used. They should have suggested adding a function index on `A ( to_char(x) )`.

Comment: _select to_char('123') from dual;-- this will work_    Yes, but it makes no sense.  '123' (enclosed in single quotes) is _already_ a character string.  So there is no reason to pass it to TO_CHAR.  Doing so merely causes oracle to have to do an implied TO_NUMBER, in order to create the correct data type input to TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can it fail?

Yes. It must put every row through `TO_NUMBER` before it can check whether or not it meets the filter condition. Therefore, if you have any one row where it will fail then it will always fail.

---

From [Oracle 12.2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) (since you tagged Oracle 12) you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
       ON (A.x = TO_NUMBER(B.y DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR))
```

---

Alternatively, put an index on `TO_CHAR(A.x)` and use your original query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   A
       INNER JOIN B
       ON (TO_CHAR(A.x) = B.y)
```

---

Also note: Having an index on `B.y` does not mean that the index will be used. If you are filtering on `TO_NUMBER(B.y)` (with or without the default on conversion error) then you would need a function-based index on the function `TO_NUMBER(B.Y)` that you are using. You should profile the queries and check the explain plans to see whether there is any improvement or change in use of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Never convert a `VARCHAR2` column that can contain non-mumeric strings `to_number`.

This can partially work, but will eventuelly definitively fail.

**Small Example**

```
create table a as
select rownum X from dual connect by level <= 10;

create table b as
select to_char(rownum) Y from dual connect by level <= 10
union all
select 'Hello' from dual;
```

This could work (as you limit the rows, so that the conversion works; if you are lucky and Oracle chooses the right execution plan; which is probable, but not guarantied;)

```
select * 
from a
join b on A.x=to_number(B.y)
where B.y =  '1';
```

But this will **fail**

```
select * 
from a
join b on A.x=to_number(B.y)

ORA-01722: invalid number
```

**Performance**

> But since there is index on Y, performance team suggested us to do A.x=to_number(B.y);

You should chalange the team, as if you use a *function* on a column (`to_number(B.y)`) index *can't be used*.

On the contrary, your original query can perfectly use the following indexes:

```
create index b_y on b(y);
create index a_x on a(x);
```

Query

```
select * 
from a
join b on to_char(A.x)=B.y
where A.x = 1;
```

Execution Plan

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS     |      |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| A_X  |     1 |     3 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| B_Y  |     1 |     2 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("A"."X"=1)
   3 - access("B"."Y"=TO_CHAR("A"."X"))
```

Comment: Even the query you suppose must work can fail. The DBMS is free to try to join all rows first and only then apply the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for recapitulating this @ThorstenKettner. This was exact my intention to point out, see the formulation: *This can partially work..*. Anyway I edited the sentence you mentioned so that no doubt can be raise. Hopefully I was not too hard against Oracle;)